# How to retrieve an array of values from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to retrieve the array of values in an ajax success method ....

here is my ajax code

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Workflows/NumberofWorkflows',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    processData: false,
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    //data: "input=" + JSON.stringify(IVRInstant.data) + "&workflowname=" + workflowname,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data[0]);
    }
});
```

And here is my controller

```
public string[] NumberofWorkflows()
 {
        string[] names = { };
        var email = Session["Username"];

        var userid = (from a in db.users
                      where a.userName == email
                      select a.userId).SingleOrDefault();


        names = (from s in db.workflows
                 where s.userId == userid
                 select s.Name).ToArray();
        return names;
    }
```

the names variable contains the list of values but i am not receiving it in the ajax method

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages in the console for this?

Comment: I am not getting any errors

Comment: the data variable in success method consists of "System.String[]" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to:

```
var arr = $.parseJSON(data);

success: function (data) {
    var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: if i place the above code it is not even showing the alertbox

Comment: try  dataType: 'json' maybe

Comment: No use even using dataType: 'json'

Comment: i previously got System.String[] in alert box

Comment: hmm, try to return a static value in your controller, to check if the error is in your controller: `return "yourArrayHere";` something that works...

Comment: When i replace public string[] NumberofWorkflows() with public string NumberofWorkflows() and return "yourArrayHere"; its showing in the alertbox

Comment: you see, JS site is fine, look further in your controller or post the question to `.net`, there is the fault i think...

Answer (score 0):

```
id_numbers = new Array();
 $.ajax({
   url:"Example.php",
   type:"POST",
  success:function(msg){
    id_numbers = msg;
  },
  "json"
});
```

**JavaScript**

```
id_numbers = JSON.parse(msg);
```

**PHP**

```
echo json_encode($id_numbers);
```

You can give a fourth parameter to jQuery to automatically decode JSON for you.